# Display all product with category in laravel

Tags: laravel

How to display all products with their categories at the same time without specifying category id or name using Laravel 7

This is my method in a controller

```
public function index() {

 $categorycats = Project::select('projects.project_category_id', 'projects.title', 'projects.slug')
            ->join('project_categories', 'project_categories.id', '=', 'projects.project_category_id')
            ->select('project_categories.id', 'project_categories.name', \DB::raw('projects.project_category_id as proname, COUNT(projects.id) as proamount'))
            ->groupBy(\DB::raw('project_category_id'))
            ->get();

}
```

This only return me Category name only, I would like to return category and its products

For example:

Category 1, product1 product 2 product3 Category 2, product4 product 5 product6

Thanks

Comment: can you show your model ?

Comment: class Project extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'slug';
    }
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProjectCategory');
    }
}


class ProjectCategory extends Model
{

    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function projects() {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}

Comment: could you add this by edit you question ? :D it is hard to read